# Naming after zip codes (not US!)

Tags: r, list, region, zipcode

In advance, I hope I've presented a data example appropriately - I haven't posted here before and I'm new to R as well. I have a LARGE dataset where I would like to create a new column with regional name (5 different) based on a lot of zip codes (1089 different) as shown below.

```
id zip 
1 8000   
2 7700 
3 1050
4 5000  
5 6880 
6 8620 


id zip  region_name
1 8000   central
2 7700   north
3 1050   capital  
4 5000   south
5 6880   central 
6 8620   central
```

Due to the many different zip codes, I have assigned each of the 1089 zip codes into five lists() according to the five regions: "north", "central", "south", "capital", and "sjaelland". Can anyone help me with a good code/solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use stack to make your zip code named list a data.frame as well and then merge/left_join the tables

**code**

```
zip_code_df <- stack(zip_code_list)
names(zip_code_df) <- c("zip", "region_name")

left_join(df, zip_code_df, by = "zip")
```

**results**

```
   id  zip region_name
1:  1 8000     central
2:  2 7700       north
3:  3 1050     capital
4:  4 5000       south
5:  5 6880     central
6:  6 8620     central
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:6, zip = c(8000L, 7700L, 1050L, 5000L, 6880L, 8620L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.frame"))

zip_code_list <- list(
  "north" = c(7700),
  "central" = c(8000, 6880, 8620),
  "capital" = c(1050),
  "south" = c(5000)
)
```